# Is it possible to initialize a std::array of std::unique_ptr in the initializer list of the constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following sort of code in mind:

```
class Surface { /* abstract base class with various properly derived classes */ };

struct ParallelSurfaces
{
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Surface>, 2> surfacePtrs;

    ParallelSurfaces()
    : surfacePtrs({std::unique_ptr<Surface>(), std::unique_ptr<Surface>()})
    { }
};
```

Yet this does not work because the copy constructor of unique_ptr is deleted. (Visual Studio 2013 reports `error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Surface,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function`)

- Is it possible to do it in the initializer list?
- Or do I have to do it in the constructor body?
- Or can I actually just leave it up to default initialization? (as I only want to have `nullptr`s stored at construction time to reset them later)

Comment: What compiler error do you get? I think this should be fine as the move constructor will be used.

Comment: It's fine [here](http://rextester.com/EUCDW65790). BTW: `std::array` will be default initialized so you don't need to do this.

Comment: Which version of VS?

Comment: hey, the compile error occurs on Visual Studio 2013. I have added this to the question details

Comment: If you want nullptr's, just drop the initialization. A `unique_ptr u` is initialized as empty, just the same as it would if you'd assign a `nullptr` to it. You can test if it's filled via the conversion to `bool`, i.e. `if(u) { /*... is filled...*/ }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long and short is that this is actually a pretty icky case in the Standard itself, which had to be fixed in C++14 if I recall correctly. So it's not a compiler bug, but should be fixed in newer compilers.

The simplest thing to do in this case is to just drop the initialization, as the default initialization of the array will produce the values you want.

Comment: I think rather than the default initialization of the array, it's the default initialization of the unique_ptr. If it were an `std::array<int,2>`, after dropping the initialization it would contain arbitrary values.

Comment: The default initialization of the array does what we want, which is to default initialize the unique_ptrs.